# Monolog Logger outputs empty arrays at the end of each log message

Tags: php, monolog

My logger object is outputting empty arrays at the end of each line - `[] []`. For example;

> [2017-08-17 12:26:02] import_log.INFO: checkForDuplicates::is_processing  [] []
>   [2017-08-17 12:26:04] import_log.INFO: is duplicate  [] []

Is there anyway I can stop this from occurring? I just want to log out without the empty arrays, ie, like the following:

> [2017-08-17 12:26:02] import_log.INFO: checkForDuplicates::is_processing
>   [2017-08-17 12:26:04] import_log.INFO: is duplicate

I am creating my own logs like so:

```
protected function importXML($fName) {

    // Create a log file for each XML file imported
    $logger = new Logger("import_log");
    $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(storage_path('./logs/' . $fName . '.log')), Logger::INFO);

    ....

    $logger->info($myString);


    ....

    $logger->info($myObject);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How not to show last bracket in a monolog log line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968967/how-not-to-show-last-bracket-in-a-monolog-log-line)

Answer (score 19):

These empty arrays are the **context** and **extra** attributes of your log entry. **Context** is provided as an additional array parameter when you add a log entry. **Extra** is populated by "processors" that you attach to your logger.

These empty arrays can be hidden:

When you don't define a `formatter` for Monolog, it will use a default `LineFormatter`. One of the [constructor parameters](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/7b992836275e09ed63c63fe33ca9993e515e6c5d/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php#L37) for a  `LineFormatter` is the option you're looking for:

```
public function __construct(string $format = null, string $dateFormat = null, bool $allowInlineLineBreaks = false, bool $ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra = false)
```

Specifically the 4th option is relevant - `bool $ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra = false`. If you create your own formatter:

```
$formatter = new LineFormatter(null, null, false, true);
```

Give it to your handler:

```
$handler = new StreamHandler(storage_path('./logs/' . $fName . '.log'));
$handler->setFormatter($formatter);
```

That should prevent the logger from showing empty arrays for "context" and "extra".

Comment: Adding to this wonderful answer, to use LineFormatter, you'll need to `use \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;`

Comment: A more readable option (Monolog v2) would be `$formatter->ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra();`, right after the `LineFormatter` instance.

Comment: Starting with PHP 8, you can also use named arguments: `new LineFormatter(ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra : true)`