# Why I am getting empty arrays at the end of error message after I send an email using SendGrid API?

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using SendGrid API to send an email. I am trying to log any error when sending an email. The response that I am getting is giving me 2 empty arrays at the end of the message which I don't know why. Please refer to the screenshot for the error message.

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQkJ.jpg)

Comment: I don't know about SendGrid, but Monolog/Laravel puts that at the end of it's logging lines. I can't remember why, though.

Comment: Yeah, it is the same case. When I log the errors it then adds two empty arrays at the end which I am curious why? :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725762/monolog-logger-outputs-empty-arrays-at-the-end-of-each-log-message might help