# Monolog messages called multiple times

Tags: php, oop, monolog

I am having a wrapper class for monolog as below

**log.php**

```
<?php

namespace Plugin\Core;

use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Level;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class Log
{

    private $logger;

    private $path;

    public function __construct($name = 'wpmatrimony', $path = NULL)
    {
   
        if(empty($path)){
            
            $path = WPMATRIMONY_PLUGIN_DIR.'./logs/'.$name.'.log';

        }

        $this->path = $path;

        $this->logger = new Logger($name);

        $this->logger->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('ASIA/KOLKATA'));

    }

    private function handler($level){

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968967/how-not-to-show-last-bracket-in-a-monolog-log-line

        $handler = new StreamHandler($this->path, $level);

        $dateFormat = "d-m-Y H:i:s";

        $handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(NULL, $dateFormat, false, true));

        return $handler;

    }

    public function info($log){

        $this->logger->pushHandler($this->handler(Level::Info));

        $this->logger->info($log);

    }

    public function debug($log){

        $this->logger->pushHandler($this->handler(Level::Debug));

        $this->logger->debug($log);

    }

    public function error($log){

        $this->logger->pushHandler($this->handler(Level::Error));

        $this->logger->error($log);

    }

    public function warning($log){

        $this->logger->pushHandler($this->handler(Level::Warning));

        $this->logger->warning($log);

    }

    public function notice($log){

        $this->logger->pushHandler($this->handler(Level::Notice));

        $this->logger->notice($log);

    }


    public function critical($log){

        $this->logger->pushHandler($this->handler(Level::Critical));

        $this->logger->critical($log);

    }

    public function alert($log){

        $this->logger->pushHandler($this->handler(Level::Alert));

        $this->logger->alert($log);

    }

    public function emergency($log){

        $this->logger->pushHandler($this->handler(Level::Emergency));

        $this->logger->emergency($log);

    }

}
```

This is working fine. But i am getting the logs increment for each lines, in below case

```
$log = new Log('test-monolog');
$log->debug('debug');
$log->info('info');
$log->warning('warning');
```

**Actual Output**

```
[30-07-2022 09:41:50] test-monolog.DEBUG: debug  
[30-07-2022 09:41:50] test-monolog.INFO: info  
[30-07-2022 09:41:50] test-monolog.INFO: info  
[30-07-2022 09:41:50] test-monolog.WARNING: warning  
[30-07-2022 09:41:50] test-monolog.WARNING: warning  
[30-07-2022 09:41:50] test-monolog.WARNING: warning
```

**Expected Output**

```
[30-07-2022 09:47:22] test-monolog.DEBUG: debug  
[30-07-2022 09:47:22] test-monolog.INFO: info  
[30-07-2022 09:47:22] test-monolog.WARNING: warning
```

If my code is like below, i am getting expected output

```
 $log = new Log('test-monolog');
 $log->debug('debug');
 $log = new Log('test-monolog');
 $log->info('info');
 $log = new Log('test-monolog');
 $log->warning('warning');
```

How can i avoid calling the Log class multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the monolog is not clearing the previous instantiation and is bubbling. So below code works.

```
<?php

namespace Plugin\Core;

use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Level;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class Log
{

   
    private $path;

    private $name;

    public function __construct($name = 'wpmatrimony', $path = NULL)
    {
   
        if(empty($path)){
            
            $path = WPMATRIMONY_PLUGIN_DIR.'./logs/'.$name.'.log';

        }

        $this->path = $path;

        $this->name = $name;

        

    }

    public  function logger($level){

        $logger = new Logger($this->name);

        $logger->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('ASIA/KOLKATA'));

        $handler = new StreamHandler($this->path, $level);

        $dateFormat = "d-m-Y H:i:s";

        $handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(NULL, $dateFormat, false, true));

        $logger->pushHandler($handler);

        return $logger;

    }

    public function info($log){

        $logger = $this->logger(Level::Info);

        $logger->info($log);

        return;

    }

    public function debug($log){

        $logger = $this->logger(Level::Debug);

        $logger->debug($log);

        return;

    }

    public function error($log){

        $logger = $this->logger(Level::Error);

        $logger->error($log);

        return;

    }

    public function warning($log){

        $logger = $this->logger(Level::warning);

        $logger->warning($log);

        return;
    }

    public function notice($log){

        $logger = $this->logger(Level::Notice);

        $logger->notice($log);

        return;

    }


    public function critical($log){

        $logger = $this->logger(Level::Critical);

        $logger->critical($log);

        return;

    }

    public function alert($log){

        $logger = $this->logger(Level::Alert);

        $logger->alert($log);

        return;

    }

    public function emergency($log){

        $logger = $this->logger(Level::Emergency);

        $logger->emergency($log);

        return;

    }

}
```